# how to get current location in three actions on phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Hi I need to get current locations for my app on three types of page,
I Have call separate functions for that three pages,

if click first page, then call first function and get current location,

I need that action on another two pages also, 
I mean like below structure,

```
function current_locations()
{
  //get locations and return as object;
}
```

First page call this function:

```
function first()
{
var loc = current_locations();
var lat=loc.latitude;
var lon=loc.longitude;
//some actions
}
```

second page call this function:

```
function second()
{
var loc = current_locations();
var lat=loc.latitude;
var lon=loc.longitude;
//some actions
}
```

third page call this function:

```
function third()
{
var loc = current_locations();
var lat=loc.latitude;
var lon=loc.longitude;
//some actions
}
```

Please help me, many time i am trying I can't get location value correctly.

Advance thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in the Geolocalizaçao API (https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-geolocation/blob/dev/doc/index.md), you can get your location with the phonegap.